# Why is MariaDB 10.1.38 not creating tablespaces?

Tags: mysql, mariadb, innodb, tablespace

I tried to create a tablespace with the following command:

```
CREATE TABLESPACE my_tablespace ADD DATAFILE 'my_tablespace.ibd' engine=InnoDB;
```

The command went fine, no error message was shown, instead it was a success, but I am unable to see any tablespaces with the following query:

```
SELECT FILE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.FILES WHERE TABLESPACE_NAME LIKE 'my_tablespace';
```

And where does this file "my_tablespace.ibd" get created in Windows?

Comment: *"why mysql (v 15.1) not creating tablespaces?"* MySQL version 15.1 ? Do a `SELECT VERSION();` and fix the version number..

Comment: Sorry, my bad, it was not 15.1, it was 10.1.38-MariaDB, can you tell me what's the problem now?

Comment: 'The CREATE TABLESPACE statement is not supported by MariaDB. It was originally inherited from MySQL NDB Cluster. In MySQL 5.7 and later, the statement is also supported for InnoDB. However, MariaDB has chosen not to include that specific feature.' https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/create-tablespace/ AND mariadb does give a warning to this effect on the execution of the create tablespace statement.

Comment: That's very bad, thanks a lot P.Salmon, but the version mentioned in Jira ticket from where on Tablespace support is to be discontinued is 10.2, while my version is 10.1.38, shouldn't I be able to use that feature then?

Comment: *"Tablespace support is to be discontinued is 10.2, while my version is 10.1.38, shouldn't I be able to use that feature then?"* No you are misreading the ticket, MariaDB never had support for those MySQL 5.7 features..   As MariaDB 10.2 was meant as drop in replaced for MySQL 5.7 expect those features older MariaDB versions will then also not have those features offcource as they are based on a older MySQL source code version.. ..

Comment: What aspect of Tablespaces did you want to take advantage of?  Maybe there is an alternative way to achieve your task.